# Request a data to Backend by using Fetch 'Get' (with this error message Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Tags: reactjs

I am just getting started learning React a few weeks ago and I tried to make a Nike website for practice. When I request a data to Backend by using fetch

p.s) (with this error message Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${API}${this.props.location.pathname}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          productsInfo: data.result,
        });
      });
    console.log('apiCheck', API);
  }
```

The request Url what I expected is "http://10.58.6.96:8000/products". However, the requestURL is "http://localhost:3000/10.58.6.96:8000/products" which includes my local address. When I console.log the API, it shows 10.58.6.96:8000 as well. Could you help me with this issue? Please let me know if you need my whole code! It would be really appreciate with your help!

Comment: what is value of `API` you got on console? what the api you trying to hit as `GET`?

Comment: can you share your code where API is mentioned

Comment: `fetch('//${API}${this.props.location.pathname}')` prepend with two slashes must do the trick

Comment: @AshishKamble my api is 10.58.6.96:8000 so when I fetch the url to backend, I will get the data what I want!

Comment: @AshishKamble the API is just export const API = '10.58.6.96:8000'; in the config.js file and I import it in the main.js!

Comment: you just can append /products at the end and your api url will get created with no errors, actually i dont know whats API value here, maybe i will edit answer according to it,

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${this.props.location.pathname}`+"/products")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          productsInfo: data.result,
        });
      });
    console.log('apiCheck', API);
  }

Comment: @bZezzz when I check the requetURL and console.log it shows {API}${this.props.location.pathname} what I expected but the backend didn't receive anything.

Comment: @JiwanJeon94 replace ' with `

Answer (score 0):

change the value of `API` in your config to `http://10.58.6.96:8000` instead of `10.58.6.96:8000`.  If the protocol isn't present (http), fetch will assume it's a relative path.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! but I don't need add https because if I add this and when I tried to console.log the address, console.log showed two https

Comment: so you get `http://localhost:3000/http://10.58.6.96:8000/products`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding two slashes must do the tricks

```js
fetch(`//${API}${this.props.location.pathname}`)
```

Comment: When I change ` to ' the error message said [ TypeError: Failed to fetch] and 500 error .. :(

Comment: http://10.58.6.96:8000/products doesn't exist ?, what does console.log of `${API}${this.props.location.pathname}` output ?

Comment: when I write fetch(`//${API}${this.props.location.pathname}`) what you said. 200 that means works as well but the products didn't show up. However, when I Type "10.58.6.96:8000/products" it works very well! I am not sure what part is wrong

Comment: when I console.log ${API}${this.props.location.pathname}, it shows 10.58.6.96:8000/products very well!

Comment: So, does your https://10.58.6.96:8000/products accept cross origin ? is it a local address ? Restricted to some ip ? Because url doesn't work for me

Comment: Oh I am sorrry. It is local address!

Comment: Please post `console.log(res.text())` output and console.log(res.json())